# Neo4j : unable to load third party jar, require for custom neo4j plugin

Tags: neo4j

I have written a custom neo4j plugin. In plugin I am using third-party gson jars.

I am able to compile it to myext.jar and kept it in plugin directory. Gson jars are in neo4j/lib folder
I am able to get all urls using http:// localhost:7474/db/data/ ..

But Whenever I call a specific API which requires GSON , it throw me error com/google/Json Parser : Class not found exception..

Can any one help me out of this:

NOTE : everything runs fine until code require GSON not executed.

Thanks

Comment: Put the gson jar also into the plugin folder.

Comment: Michael , its resolved . I was putting some wrong files